# how to handle ValueState of HyperLogLogPlus in flink

Tags: apache-flink

When using ValueState of java object that is not POJO, like HyperLogLogPlus, how to handle the serialization problem?

I have tried defining HyperLogLogPlusSerializer extends TypeSerializer, code as:

```
public class HyperLogLogPlusSerializer extends TypeSerializer<HyperLogLogPlus> {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HyperLogLogPlusSerializer.class);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public boolean isImmutableType() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeSerializer<HyperLogLogPlus> duplicate() {
        logger.info("duplicate invoked.");
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public HyperLogLogPlus createInstance() {
        return new HyperLogLogPlus(20,25);
    }

    @Override
    public HyperLogLogPlus copy(HyperLogLogPlus from) {
        try{
            byte[] bytes = from.getBytes();
            return HyperLogLogPlus.Builder.build(bytes);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public HyperLogLogPlus copy(HyperLogLogPlus from, HyperLogLogPlus reuse) {
        return copy(from);
    }

    @Override
    public int getLength() {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(HyperLogLogPlus record, DataOutputView target) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = record.getBytes();
        target.writeInt(bytes.length);
        target.write(bytes);
        logger.info("serialize:{}", bytes.length);
    }

    @Override
    public HyperLogLogPlus deserialize(DataInputView source) throws IOException {
        int dataLength = source.readInt();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[dataLength];
        source.read(bytes);
        logger.info("deserialize:{}", bytes.length);
        return HyperLogLogPlus.Builder.build(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public HyperLogLogPlus deserialize(HyperLogLogPlus reuse, DataInputView source) throws IOException {
        return deserialize(source);
    }

    @Override
    public void copy(DataInputView source, DataOutputView target) throws IOException {
        int dataLength = source.readInt();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[dataLength];
        source.read(bytes);
        target.writeInt(dataLength);
        target.write(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof HyperLogLogPlusSerializer){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canEqual(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof HyperLogLogPlusSerializer;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getClass().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public TypeSerializerSnapshot<HyperLogLogPlus> snapshotConfiguration() {
        logger.error("snapshotConfiguration invoked.");
        return new HyperLogLogPlusSerializerSnapshot();
    }

    public static final class HyperLogLogPlusSerializerSnapshot extends SimpleTypeSerializerSnapshot<HyperLogLogPlus> {

        public HyperLogLogPlusSerializerSnapshot(){
            super(HyperLogLogPlusSerializer.class);
        }
    }
}
```

ValueState defined:

```
private ValueState<HyperLogLogPlus> showUVState;

showUVState = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor("showUVState",new HyperLogLogPlusSerializer()));
```

flink job runs nomally with checkpoint, but throws Exception when restoring from savepoint:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore keyed state backend for LegacyKeyedProcessOperator_306d8342cb5b2ad8b53f1be57f65bee8_(28/32) from any of the 1 provided restore options.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:137)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:135)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.readKeyGroupStateData(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:479)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.readStateHandleStateData(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:453)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.restorePartitionedState(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:410)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.restore(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:358)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapKeyedStateBackend.restore(HeapKeyedStateBackend.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:123)
```

Answer (score 0):

`HyperLogLogPlus` is serializable and has a `Builder` object which can deserialize a byte array representation to a `HyperLogLogPlus` object. Therefore, you can:

1. Get a byte array representation of the `HyperLogLogPlus` object by calling `.getBytes()`.
2. Store the byte array with kryo
3. On deserialization, call `Builder.build(byte[])` and receive an `HyperLogLogPlus` object.

Comment: yes, I have defined HyperLogLogPlusSerializer extends TypeSerializer<HyperLogLogPlus>, and step1 and step3 are used, but when restoring from savepoint, there is some problem which we could not understand.

Comment: what's the step2? it seems not in TypeSerializer<HyperLogLogPlus>

Comment: Step 2 is indeed in TypeSerializer. Could you share the code you used for TypeSerializer?

Comment: HyperLogLogPlusSerializer code has been posted above.

Comment: You could try to register a custom serializer instead: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/custom_serializers.html

Comment: custom serializer that extends TypeSerializer can't be registered, because args doesn't match.